# Filter URL and shortcodes from the_excerpt

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

I just noticed a weird behavior on a theme I'm working on. If I have a post with just one link or shortcode, `the_excerpt` will print that URL or shortcode. But if I have some text in the post, below or above the same link or shortcode, `the_excerpt` returns only the text.

Why is this happening? And is there a simple way to remove the links and shortcodes if there is no other content in a post?

The only filters I used on `the_excerpt` are the `excerpt_more` and `excerpt_length`. Also, in my loop I'm using `the_excerpt();`.

**-- Later edit --**

After exchanging a few comments below it became obvious that I should also include a few examples in this questions to clarify two thinks: 1) the default behavior of `the_excerpt` and 2) the case and solution I'm looking for.

Default behavior of `the_excerpt`:

1. If there is **content** below or above a shortcode, only the content (text) will be shown by `the_excerpt`.
2. If there is **no content** below or above a shortcode that contains an URL, the URL will be shown by `the_excerpt`. The same happens if instead of a shortcode thre's an embeddable URL (like a youtube link).

Example: If I have in a post only this shortcode `[audio mp3="http://path.to.file"][/audio]`, `the excerpt` will print only the URL -> `http://path.to.file`.

What I would want to do is this: if `the_excerpt` displays only an URL, then display 'no content'.

Comment: The codex says "An auto-generated excerpt will also have all shortcodes and tags removed". Can you remove your filters and check if the problem persists?.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but the post will still display the URL of the shortcode (if it's an youtube, mp3 or anything embeddable). If I put a filter to remove the URL from the_excerpt, then the post will show the shortcode. Maybe if I try a `regex` to remove the URLs and then also a `strip_shortcodes`...

Comment: If you have a shortcode with a URL inside the shortcode, auto-generated excerpt will print the URL, not the shortcode, and that is the normal and correct behaviour. If you has active filters to alter that behaviour, please post the code of those filters.

Comment: Ok, so that's the normal behavior of the_excerpt: to show the URL. Is there any way I could hide the URLs? And no, I don't have any active filters.

Comment: I thought you had active filters because you said that. I'm sorry but I was wrong if you have something like `[shortcode]http://someurl.com[/shortcode]`, the auto generated excerpt should print empty string, that is nothing. If you have "Some text [shortcode]http://someurl.com[/shortcode]", then the auto generated excerpt should print only "Some text". You should post the actual code you are using, include any excerpt filter, content filter and the shortcode code. If you have only a link, the autogenerated excerpt should print the anchor text of the link.

Comment: I've updated the questions with a few examples, hope now it's a bit clearer what I'm looking for. Regarding any filters, as I said in the original question, except for the `excerpt_more` and `excerpt_length` I don't have any other filters on excerpt or content.

Comment: Please post the full code of the shortcode. I don't mean `[audio mp3="http://path.to.file"][/audio]`, I mean the PHP script that handle that shortcode.

Comment: But it's not a custom shortcode: http://codex.wordpress.org/Audio_Shortcode

Comment: So it is a core shortcode and you have no custom code that can be affecting shortcode or excerpt output. With this information is imposible to know what is happening to you. Try to deactivate all plugins and use a core theme to see if the problem persists. Maybe some plugin or code in the theme is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when outputting you can use `strip_shortcodes( $content )` which will remove all shortcode tags from the given content.